# Use global.asax to trigger event on master.page to show application errors

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-ajax, global-asax, modalpopupextender

I would like to use my AJAX-enabled VB web application's gloabal.asax application_error sub to manage all my error handling. However, instead of just sending the user to an error page, I would like to show the error message to the user via a modalpopupextender control located inside the site's master.page.

Can someone please explain in detail how this can be accomplished? I have managed to do this using a single aspx page (with the `modalpopupextender` dynamically loaded there via a placeholder) and my error-handler class raising the event to show the popup back on the page when an error occurs, but have not had success in doing the same using the master.page.